# LED driver circuit with both analog and pwm control

Tags: led, pwm, driver, constant-current

I would like to design an LED driver circuit that allows for simultaneous analog and pwm control. That is, I would like to set the the LED current using an analog signal and then be able to switch using another pwm signal. I have a design with the analog control shown below. Is there a simple way to add the pwm control to this circuit?

[image: LED driver with analog control]

I realize that there are numerous high level components that solve this problem but I am using this as a test case to learn basic electronics and would like to solve it using low level components.

Comment: if the OP-AMP you choose allows suficient inout range ypu couldl just put pwm input onto the non-inverting input of the op-amp.

Answer (score 2):

You can just add the control to the amplifier:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1hPhr.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Some notes:

1. The input [common mode](http://www.analog.com/media/en/training-seminars/tutorials/MT-041.pdf) range of the amplifier must go all the way to ground.
2. The PWM control is inverted: A high on the PWM input will turn the LED off.
3. The PWM rate will be limited by the transient performance of the amplifier.

Comment: I tried the proposal but I have som problems in the off state. The voltage on the + input on the op-amp goes to 20 mV and not to zero. The current through the LED is around 1 mA when the analog signal is at its maximum and it is enough to get light. I wonder if it would be possible to have the pwm-input between the LED and the npn-transistor...